# why do unity 2020 and 2019 keep crashing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i installed those two editors through unity hub. When i opened either of them, they take forever on the unity loading screen. When the actual editor tab pops out after the loading screen is finally gone, it consumes even more time then the blank editor just crashes. the unity crash report in 2020 says my gpu got reset due to overload while 2019 cant find a reason. my gpu, windows 10, and unity hub are all updated.  my computer had no problem with the 2017 version. please help. thanks.

Comment: Same here, brother... Just keep updating and hope for a better version. :)

Comment: Could post more detail info about the crash, and contact unity forum for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to delete all folders about Unity and download Unity again.Probably there are some missing files.